# Deploying a serverless application with Nest.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, nestjs

I have an application using Nest.js, and I'd like to deploy it using API Gateway + Lambda functions.

I have some experience with AWS, but it's my first time with a serverless application.

I searched for some things but almost everything that I found uses the Serverless framework, and I would like to do it using the AWS SDK.

I have an API with 4 endpoints, I want to use API Gateway and a single Lambda function to run the application.

Any tips on how I could do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: so what specifically are you trying to accomplish that this tutorial doesn't explain: [Deploy a NestJS App with Serverless Framework](https://blog.theodo.com/2019/06/deploy-a-nestjs-app-in-5-minutes-with-serverless-framework/)?  Why exactly do you need the "AWS SDK"?  Please clarify what you're trying to do, outside of getting your NestJS app running "serverless" on AWS.

Comment: I edited the question with what I want to accomplish. The link you sent actually explains how to deploy the application in the way I want. To be honest there's not an specific reason for me to use the SDK, I guess that it could be easier to use only the SDK rather than the whole Serverless framework.

Comment: This is not the right way to ask a specific question on stackoverflow. It makes no sense to ask here for full recipes. You need to ask a specific code question including a code example.